# 16.04LTS TightVNC window mangement

Tags: xfce, vnc

I have used this setup on other systems before with no problem,so I don't understand it now, but I need an assist to sort it out.

TightVncServer with xfce4 and xfce4-goodies, launched from vncserver starts just fine, but if a window passes into the background I lose all interactivity with it. Current xstartup follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce &
```

A

Comment: It appears to be related with xfce4 window manager... but not 100%